# Is failing Faerie Fire's dexerity save neccessary for a creature to be given advantage against?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

I am confused. I have always played that *[Faerie Fire](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Faerie%20Fire#content)* grants advantage regardless of whether a creature passes its dexterity save against it. However, that does seem to make a level one spell awfully powerful.

Are there any rulings that would explain whether failing the Dexterity save is necessary to bestow advantage against creatures in the area of effect when cast?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No ruling necessary, just the text of the spell:

> Any creature in the area when the spell is cast is also outlined in light ***if it fails a Dexterity saving throw.*** (PHB p.239, emphasis mine.)

*Faerie fire* outlines objects. It also outlines those creatures that fail the save. It does nothing to those creatures that pass the save.

Moving on...

> Any attack roll against ***an affected creature or object has advantage***.... (Emphasis mine again.)

Only the creatures lit up by the spell are the ones "affected," so only against them are attacks advantaged.